# Make node/npm work without problems

Tags: node.js, osx-lion, npm

i started to play around with node.js and npm installer. My Problem: "npm install" and "npm install -g something" sometimes produces errors like this.

I was wondering **how to reinstall node** just to make sure my machine is not responsible for all this errorr?

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '../index'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (module.js:370:17)
```

Comment: That depends. How did you install node? What OS / distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is some problem finding the path to your installed module. If you have installed it globally, you can try the following.

```
require.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');
require('blah');
```

I think this should solve the issue. Let me know if it doesn't work out.

(I wanted to reply to your comment but I couldn't since I don't have enough reputation points).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I had the same problem too (on OSX, same error message, etc), here is the answer in case someone else finds this on Google.

The problem is that there were two versions of node installed: one in `/usr/bin`, and the new one in `/usr/local/bin`. So the following makes everything work again:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/npm
```